# Springboot not recognized on IntelliJ

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea

Even after installing Java and Maven, creating a spring project from springinitializr is facing an issue. The issue is that the project is not recognised as spring project, the annotations, import nothing are working. Can anyone please help out

I tried to redo the process, but things were same. Is any settings.xml needs to be made but I don't see it as necessity.

Comment: Try to click on `Reload All Maven Projects` in Maven tool window https://prnt.sc/IIz7n_Ss9vfw. If the problem remains, try to create a new project as per https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/your-first-spring-application.html

Answer (score 1):

When opening your project in intellij. you should do so via the import > new Project and choose the `pom.xml` for the generated project from spring initialize. This way it can resolve dependencies and properly open your project.

- if the problem persists you can go to your MainApplication.java > right click > run as spring boot project.

If it does not put the configuration on the run shortcut on the up right of the application you can configure it by adding the command : `mvn spring-boot:run` and add other configurations id desired.

Comment: I found out that I was using an older version of IntelliJ, an update solved the issue. But anyway thanks.